# Difference between [].each & [].array.inject implementation (Ruby Monk Challenge)

Tags: arrays, inject

I am trying to solve the Ruby Monk Primer "Orders and Costs" problem. 
https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/155-restaurant

I have devised a solution that only works when one order is passed, but not multiple orders.

I am having a hard time understanding how my code is functionally different than the suggested answer. I also do not understand how Ruby Monk is passing "multiple orders". Any clarification between Inject and .each would be extremely helpful.

```
class Restaurant
  def initialize(menu)
  @menu = menu
end

def cost(*orders)
  orders.inject(0) do | total_cost, order | 
    order.each { | item, qt | total_cost = total_cost + @menu[item] * qt }
    return total_cost
  end
end
end
```

Compared to Ruby Monk's code:

```
def cost(*orders)
   orders.inject(0) do |total_cost, order|
   total_cost + order.keys.inject(0) {|cost, key| cost +  @menu[key]*order[key] }
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation using each is actually fine. The problem is that by explicitly returning total_cost, you are exiting the function prematurely. Ruby will implicitly return the last thing to be evaluated, so remove the word "return" and your solution will work!